# Error signup Nodejs (ERR NAME NOT RESOLVED)

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

[image: Exception]

```
const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  setAvatar(file);
};
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
  const newForm = new FormData();
  newForm.append("file", avatar);
  newForm.append("name", name);
  newForm.append("email", email);
  newForm.append("password", password);
  axios
    .post(`${server}/user/create-user`, newForm, config)
    .then((res) => {
      toast.success(res.data.message);
      setName("");
      setEmail("");
      setPassword("");
      setAvatar();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      toast.error(error.message);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your address, `loaclhost:8000` should be changed to `localhost:8000`

(The browser is trying to resolve `loaclhost`, but doesn't know what ip address it points to)